# What's the idiomatic way of handling errors while walking the parse tree in ANTLR4?

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr4

I'm just getting started with ANTLR4 and I'm in the process of creating a listener that walks the parse tree.  I also have a custom error listener added the `Parser` instance; to build on this, I'd like any errors I report during a call to `ParseTreeWalker.walk()` to also go to the parser's error listeners.  It's occurred to me that I could call `Parser.getErrorListeners()` and inject it to my listener class, but I was hoping for something a little more baked-in.

While I'm at it, I need a means of determining a given node's row and column number when reporting the error.  Does everyone just roll their own when it comes to reporting errors found by a listener or visitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`Parser.notifyErrorListeners`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html#notifyErrorListeners%28java.lang.String%29).

The row and column numbers are available by calling `Token.getLine()` and `Token.getCharPositionInLine()`. You can retrieve the `Token` instance associated with any `TerminalNode` in the parse tree by calling `TerminalNode.getSymbol()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  So is the assumption that the listener stores a reference to the parser prior to walking the tree?  The `ParseTree` itself doesn't keep a reference to the parser, does it?

Comment: I don't think there's an established convention for this yet.